# Move Ad Banner down below Status Bar using NSLayoutConstraint Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

In Swift, I am trying to add a Google Smart Ad Banner using NSLayoutConstraints at the top of the view, but below the status bar by 14 points.  I've been trying for ages now with various different attributes and top or topLayoutGuide.

[Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9kGe.jpg)

```
let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView, attribute: .centerX,
                                     relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView, attribute: .top,
                                relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 14)

self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
self.view.addConstraint(xConstraint)
self.view.addConstraint(pinTop)
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re pinning the banner to the top of the `topLayoutGuide`, but what you really want is the *bottom* of the `topLayoutGuide`, so that it will start below the status bar:

```
let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView, 
                                attribute: .top,
                                relatedBy: .equal, 
                                toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, 
                                attribute: .bottom, 
                                multiplier: 1, 
                                constant: 14)
```